# How to keep local when I see ERROR: [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)

Tags: git

When using `git push`, I saw the error:

```
[rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

I have double checked and I am 100% sure I want to keep the local master branch's files and folders. And I have also double-checked that the remote bitbucket's master is outdated and not what I want to keep.

So can I just `git push --force`? Or is there any other way? I am afraid that `git pull` will destroy all my local files.

I am the only programmer in this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be extremely careful about using `git push --force` if someone else has pulled down changes from the repo. But it sounds like you are the sole user? In that case it seems reasonable to me in your situation.

If you want to get down the remote changes for comparison and possible merge, you can `git fetch` them. That will not modify your local branches in any way.

Comment: Yes, I create the project and so far I am the only user of it. By the way, what's your suggestion, do I even need to use `git branch` function? Since I am the only user, so I guess I can always work on the branch of `master`, and I dont need to create any new branches, right?

Comment: @Daniel Creating local branching is encouraged even if you're a sole developer on the project. It is a good convention to keep the code in your master branch in a working condition at all times. So, when you want to do something experimental or just want to try out a few things, doing this in a separate branch would be the best approach.

Comment: As a single user, the need for branches is certainly less. You could still use branches for developing different features that you want to switch between. Also, if you want to do serious release work, you may want release branches. I like this strategy http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ but it aims at bigger teams than one. You could pick a subset of it.